# Media player for Drupal 7 that can play remote http-accessible files

Tags: 7, media

I'm looking for a simple module for Drupal 7 to be able to have an embedded player that can play files that are stored on a different server and that is accessible via this URL:

http://[servername]/WebPlay/MCWS/v1/File/GetFile?File=[FileID]

(where [servername] is not a drupal site)

I think that file formats may vary, but should be the common ones (mkv, avi or flv containers).

Ideally the player should be able to play remote audio and locally (i.e. inside drupal) stored audio\video as well.

Note that the URL to be played (the one above) is stored in Drupal in a Token Field, but if needed by the player I can try and store it in a different field type.

Can anyone help me? None of the players I can find on drupal.org for D7 have documentation on how to do what I need and to me is not even clear if those players can do it (let alone how).

I tried the MediaElement + Link combo (putting the URL in the link field), but there's an issue with query parametesr in URLs being stripped, so it's not working.
The say the issue [is fixed](http://drupal.org/node/1388214), but I tested it with MediaElement latest version (7.x-1.2) and it's still there.

Answer (score 2):

If this were me; I'd be using a media-compatible media player (such as MediaElement with the 2.x branch of Media) and using remote stream wrapper to allow me to place the remote URL into the media field: https://drupal.org/project/remote_stream_wrapper

This should let you use local media **or** remote media that the media player can play, and will keep things tidy for you to manage.

/Robin

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I believe the [MediaFront](https://www.drupal.org/project/mediafront) module can do this.

Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... is a front end media solution for Drupal. It employs an innovative and intuitive administration interface that allows the website administrator to completely customize the front end media experience for their users without writing any code. In addition, this module provides an interface to which 3rd party media players can integrate and utilize settings presets to display rich media.